# How to install 'rar' (from command line only)

Tags: installation, command-line, rar

My `/etc/apt/sources.list` (Ubuntu 13.10) contains:

```
deb http://... saucy main universe multiverse
deb-src http://... saucy main universe multiverse
```

According to other posts such as [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/244198/how-to-install-rar-no-installation-candidate), the 'multiverse' part is important. Although this is there, `sudo apt-get update; sudo apt-get install rar` returns `E: Package rar has no installation candidate`. What am I missing?

Note: This is actually Ubuntu 13.10 running on an Android 4.4.2 smartphone, which is one of the reasons why I am limited to the terminal to solve this problem.

Comment: maybe licensing issues prevent the non-free rar package from being included in the Android repositories?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I look at [this](http://packages.ubuntu.com/saucy/rar), then I think that there is no ARM version of the `rar` package in the repo.

Comment: okay, this seems a valid reason.

Answer (score 0):

You need an x86 emulator to install and run the rar package.
First, install the `qemu-user` package like another ARM Packages.

Second, enable the i386 repository (not recommend), or grab the newest rar binary from rarlab site (it's x86 only).

Finally, run the rar binary using the `qemu-i386` emulator, like this:

```
$ qemu-i386 /usr/bin/rar [option] archive.rar [working folder]
```

With some shell script programing, you can simply this trick.